# field went missing after logging in again

Tags: custom-field, standard-objects, recycle-bin

I have created few fields of type Text on Account object in **Test environment** from the process "**Setup > Object Manager> Account> Fields and Relationships > New**". I checked the fields Account object using "Setup > Object Manager> Account> Fields and Relationships" they were present. Later on, I *logged in Next day* to the same environment but I am unable to see those fields on Account object. I also checked the Recycle bin but they are not there either.

Any idea what the could be problem?

Comment: Also, the fields are not showing in "Recent" activities

Comment: Field and object operations appear in Setup > Audit Trail.  Recycle Bin is for data records.  Also, what specifically do you mean by "Test Environment"?  Is this a sandbox from production, or a separate Developer Edition instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be 3 possibilities:

1. Other user might have deleted the fields. You can check this in the setup audit trail that whether the fields were created or not or someonce deleted.
2. You might checking in the wrong org. Please verify whether you are logged in to the correct org.
3. If it is a sandbox org, then there is a possibility that the Sandbox might have refreshed yesterday after the field creation.

Comment: I have checked, the org is correct. Also it is the sandbox org. considering point 3, if a sandbox is refreshed then what has happened to the fields I have created? I can see 
 other custom fields that I have created earlier does sandbox refresh works on some time basis?

Comment: sandbox refresh will blow away all your changes that have yet to be deployed to the org from whence the refresh is initiated.